# iScroll Issue on iPad safari

Tags: ipad, safari, scroll, iscroll

I am trying to use iScroll for my webpage and it is behaving weird.

My markup looks something like this.

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="some-header">
   </div>
   <div id="wrapper">
       <ul>
          <li></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now both header and wrapper have heights and they both are positioned absolute. 
when I try to scroll, it does scroll but its kind of stuck, when I stop scrolling it returns back to the starting point. Weird :(

Any Sugestions.

btw this is on ipad safari.

Thanks 
Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with you.Did you use ajax the render in the scroller element.

Finally I use iscroll pull to refresh to solve this problem.

This is the question I asked : [When I am using ajax to render the Scroller part iScroll doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602997/when-i-am-using-ajax-to-render-the-scroller-part-iscroll-doesnt-work/10603363#10603363)