# When I am using ajax to render the Scroller part iScroll doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, iscroll

I met a strange problem.

If I use "for loop" to render html into scroller part,everything works well.

But when I am using ajax to render my data into scroller part.iScroll doesn't work(can't scroll).

This is my url : http://yuanwang.sinaapp.com/8505/item.html

You can copy my code and try yourself.

Open the item.js and try to run "for loop",you can see everything runs well.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question or did my suggestion not get you going in the right direction? Be sure to accept an answer if it solves the issue for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting up your iScroll inside the success function of your `.ajax()` call? It looks like you're trying various iterations of calling `loaded` after various timed events but I think you'll find more success if you set it up once all the DOM elements have been added *inside your* `.success()` function.

Perhaps something like this:

```
for ...
    for ...
        $('#thelist').append("<li>"+ co...
    }
}
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
```

**Update**:

Or just call your `loaded()` function once everything has been added.

Full disclosure: I haven't used iScroll ever so there may be a mistake in your implementation that I wouldn't notice. You may have to do something with your `myScroll` after you have created a new instance of `iScroll`. I'm not sure.

Let me know if this doesn't address your situation.

Comment: Follow your answers and I try to call loaded() after all elements loaded.But It still had problems.I think that there is a bug in iScroll.I commit an issue to iScroll github project.But no one answers my yet.Last,I use iScroll "pull to refresh" code to solve my problem.( :-( feel shamed about my poor English) http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/

Comment: Besides,I met another problem.I added iframe into the page.But it can't scroll in any ios safari browsers.

Comment: I will follow this problem and try to test the code later.Thanks again.Now return to my project. :-)

Comment: @CashLee李秉骏, 谢谢. I'm ashamed at my poor Chinese :-) I'm glad it sounds like you are on your way. I wish you success.